# Why do Google events that I create on repeat include a date that I never selected?

Tags: google-calendar

[image][image]

I created an all-day event to help me remember my husband's shift schedule. Every other Monday and Tuesday, he works. After creating an event, I go into Custom Recurrence and specifically selected [only] M and T for Monday and Tuesday. After saving the event, my calendar shows a recurring Monday and Tuesday event, PLUS an additional Tuesday and Wednesday event with the exact same information as the Monday and Tuesday recurring event. Under the Tuesday and Wednesday event, it even shows "M and T" as selected under Custom Recurrence, which isn't right. Help?? *I've tried deleting the extra event, but it only deletes EVERYTHING.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah! I see the problem. Your events are each two days long, so the calendar is working correctly in that it's creating a two-day event starting Monday, and another two-day event starting on Tuesday.

To fix this, either:

- Change the event to be a single day, OR
- Change the two-day event to repeat every Monday

Comment: Oh my word...that makes absolute sense! Thank you!!

Comment: Yay! It's been fixed...THANK YOU!

Comment: @Marie: Happy to help.